# The term 'Test-AzureRmDeployment' is not recognized as the name

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I just got a task to test the Deployment of an Azure set of resources,
but I got this messages when validating from Visual Studio 2019

> The term 'Test-AzureRmDeployment' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again

I already reinstalled the Azure PowerShell module with these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0) 
and restarted VS, but I keep gettings these errors.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I restarted VS after installing and now I get this message: The 'Test-AzureRmDeployment' command was found in the module 
'AzureRM.Resources', but the module could not be loaded

Answer (score 1):

right, this one is easier, try doing `Import-Module AzureRM.Resources` and it would throw a specific error why it failed to load. You are, most likely, using both Az and AzureRM modules together and that would not work. What I suggest you do - remove AzureRM module(s).

1. close all powershell windows\processes
2. go to the folder where the modules are located on your system ( default is  `c:\program files x64\windowspowershellmodules` )
3. Delete all folders that have `AzureRM` in their name
4. Install Az module (Install-Module Az -AllowClobber)
5. Enable backwards compatibility (`Enable-AzureRmAlias`).

If that doesn't work, i suggest you remove both `AzureRM` and `Az` modules from the system and proceed with installing only `Az` module